# Sport activity or a sports activity?

Tags: word-choice

A sport activity or a sports activity?

> a sport activity
>   a sport**s** activity

Are these phrases both correct?

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of [Why do people say “sports shoes” but not “sport shoes”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118179/why-do-people-say-sports-shoes-but-not-sport-shoes), but that one has no upvoted or accepted answers. There's also [“Sport” vs “Sports” Origin](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212851/sport-vs-sports-origin) on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

The plural is the usual way to express this

> a sport**s** activity

as in

> He is active in sport**s**.

Your phrase might also be said as

> a sport**ing** activity

but

> sporting

sometimes has a slightly different meaning than

> sports

Comment: This is an American answer. In British English, "He is active in sports" would be used only where the person was active in more than one different sport. In attributive use, neither "a sport activity" nor "a sports activity" sounds right - I would say "a sporting activity".