# Sports or sport

Tags: word-choice

What should I use in my sentence "sports" or "sport"?

> Yoga is not a sport,  but it also has a part of sports, because there is a physical activity.

I think there should be "a" before "activity".

Comment: There should not be **a** before *physical activity*, because **a** implies *one* specific physical activity, like there is exactly one physical activity in yoga.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sport activity or a sports activity?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121851/sport-activity-or-a-sports-activity)

Comment: The word ***also*** is non-idiomatic in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence has a couple of issues.

> Yoga is not a sport

this part is fine.

> , but it also has

This part is not.  "but also" is almost exclusively used with something like "not only" as in "He’s not only intelligent but also funny."

> a part of sports,

This sounds awkward.  I would word it as "contains an element of sports"

> , because there is a physical activity

There should not be an 'a' here because it does not have a singular activity, but many. Also, the comma should not be there

Overall, I would rephrase it as:

> Yoga is not a sport, but it has an element of sports because there is physical activity.

Comment: Can I use "a sports" in the first sentence and  "sport" in the second? Or either "sports" or "sport" in  both? "Yoga is not a sports, but it has an element of sport because there is physical activity.

Comment: You definitely can NOT use "a sports" in the first sentence.  You can use "sport" in the second, although it might sound a little old-fashioned or odd